# Spring + Spring Security + Hibernate org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-security

I have a problem with deploying my application. I my webapp I am using Spring, Spring Security and Hibernate.

While deploying i am geeting this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary
```

Here is my configuration files:

applicationContex.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="

<context:component-scan base-package="pl.modern" />

<mvc:annotation-driven /> 

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> 

<import resource="trace-context.xml"/>

<!-- Imports datasource configuration -->
<import resource="spring-data.xml"/>


<bean id="deployProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean"/>


</beans>
```

spring-data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa1
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">

<jee:jndi-lookup id="dbDataSource" jndi-name="java:/modernSoft"
    expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />


<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource" ref="dbDataSource"/>
    <!--<property name="packagesToScan" value="pl.modern" />-->
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
        </props>
    </property>


</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" 
    p:persistenceXmlLocation="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml"
    p:persistenceUnitName="my-pu"
    p:dataSource-ref="dbDataSource"/>


<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

spring-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.1.xsd">



    <http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">



    <intercept-url pattern="/login.do" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/logout.do" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/loginfailed.do" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />


    <form-login login-page="/login.do"
        default-target-url="/home/index.do" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed.do" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout.do" />
</http> 

<authentication-manager>

    <authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="userAuthentication" >
        <password-encoder hash="md5"/>
        </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

trace-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd">

<!-- For parsing classes with @Aspect annotation -->
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

<bean id="customizableTraceInterceptor" class="pl.modern.modernsoft.aop.TraceInterceptor"
    p:enterMessage="Entering $[targetClassShortName].$[methodName]($[arguments])"
    p:exitMessage="Leaving $[targetClassShortName].$[methodName](): $[returnValue]"/>

<aop:config>
  <aop:advisor advice-ref="customizableTraceInterceptor" pointcut="execution(public * pl.modern.services..*(..))"/>
  <aop:advisor advice-ref="customizableTraceInterceptor" pointcut="execution(public * pl.modern.modernsoft.webapp..*(..))"/>
</aop:config>

</beans>
```

webapp-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    ">

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

And to show that i am using only one version of spring here is my mvn dependency:tree file:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Parent project
[INFO] Encje itd.
[INFO] API do DAO
[INFO] API usług
[INFO] Implementacja backend-API za pomocą hibernate
[INFO] Implementacja usług
[INFO] WebApp Maven Webapp
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Parent project 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ ModernSoft ---
[INFO] pl.modern:ModernSoft:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Encje itd. 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ model ---
[INFO] pl.modern:model:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- javax:javaee-api:jar:6.0:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building API do DAO 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ backend-API ---
[INFO] pl.modern:backend-API:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- pl.modern:model:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax:javaee-api:jar:6.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building API usług 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ service-API ---
[INFO] pl.modern:service-API:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- pl.modern:model:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax:javaee-api:jar:6.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] \- pl.modern:backend-API:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]       +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]       \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Implementacja backend-API za pomocą hibernate 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ backend-DB ---
[INFO] pl.modern:backend-DB:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- pl.modern:backend-API:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- pl.modern:model:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax:javaee-api:jar:6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] \- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO]    +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO]    \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Implementacja usług 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ service-Impl ---
[INFO] pl.modern:service-Impl:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- pl.modern:service-API:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- pl.modern:model:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax:javaee-api:jar:6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- pl.modern:backend-API:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] \- pl.modern:backend-DB:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO]    \- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO]       +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO]       \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building WebApp Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The artifact aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.5.4 has been relocated to org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.5.4
[WARNING] The artifact aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.5.4 has been relocated to org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.5.4
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ WebApp ---
[WARNING] The artifact aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.5.4 has been relocated to org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.5.4
[WARNING] The artifact aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.5.4 has been relocated to org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.5.4
[INFO] pl.modern.ModernSoft:WebApp:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- pl.modern:service-Impl:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- pl.modern:service-API:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- pl.modern:model:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- javax:javaee-api:jar:6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- pl.modern:backend-API:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- pl.modern:backend-DB:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |     +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |        +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:20040616:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:3.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Parent project ..................................... SUCCESS [  0.668 s]
[INFO] Encje itd. ......................................... SUCCESS [  0.040 s]
[INFO] API do DAO ......................................... SUCCESS [  0.022 s]
[INFO] API usług .......................................... SUCCESS [  0.012 s]
[INFO] Implementacja backend-API za pomocą hibernate ...... SUCCESS [  0.036 s]
[INFO] Implementacja usług ................................ SUCCESS [  0.028 s]
[INFO] WebApp Maven Webapp ................................ SUCCESS [  0.078 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.223 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-10-18T23:33:11+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/303M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I cant find any good answer, and i have already tryied a lot of different versions of spring and hiberneta, without any results.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT 1**

After Changing spring 4.1.1 to 3.2.6 I have another error showing up while deploying:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getConnectionProvider()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means your version have conflict, in your trace-context.xml, aop and beans version should be the same as other files.

Comment: after commenting trace-context.xml the erorr still appears

Comment: Open the POM GRAPH, check the version which isn't 4.1exist in your maven complier. Sometimes the version you didn't add to the program, but it add into by other jar files cause they depends on. So find the jar,  remove it at pom but import it manually. See also:http://blog.csdn.net/robert_lizhiqiang/article/details/39997621

Comment: There aren't any other versions in my graph, because in my parent pom I have adependencyManagement with spring-4.1.1-bom so everything should be okay.

Comment: I didn't mean you add different versions in your pom, I mean maybe the other dependency  add other versions unexpected. (for example，if you add  the  jcaptcha-all in your pom, it will add spring 2.0 when you running the program, because it depends on 2.0. but the program already have spring-core 4.0. So it turn out conflict)  So I suggest checking it out.(My god! I edit by my smartphone. TOO TIRED!)

Answer (score 0):

Method below i.e.

```
org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils#registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(ParserContext, Object)
```

was removed in Spring 4.0.X.RELEASE, but it seems either your Spring Security library need it. You will have to downgrade to Spring 3.2.X.RELEASE.